# Select rows with each record's creation order per day

Tags: php, mysql, sql, count, subquery

I want to select all rows from my table but also contain the which value for each row in that row's creation day.

More detailed: "1st record of that day, 2nd record of that day".

For example, assume I have this table with rows:

```
name | created_at
-----------------
john | 2013-02-04 10:00
bob  | 2013-02-04 14:00
dale | 2013-02-05 09:00
lucy | 2013-02-06 11:00
sean | 2013-02-06 13:00
sal  | 2013-02-06 18:00
```

So when I select all these values, I need results as:

```
name | created_at       | which_record
---------------------------------------
john | 2013-02-04 10:00 | 1
bob  | 2013-02-04 14:00 | 2
dale | 2013-02-05 09:00 | 1
lucy | 2013-02-06 11:00 | 1
sean | 2013-02-06 13:00 | 2
sal  | 2013-02-06 18:00 | 3
```

Is there a way to get this `which_record` values without selecting the values and calculating again for each record or complicated subqueries?

I can either select all and generate this `which_record` per record or I can select previous records count for each record but I'm worried if running this subquery for each row would slow down the response.

Any alternatives or suggestions?

Comment: this is your order table?

Comment: I'm wondering if a trigger could do the job in your case?
Each time you add a row in your table, it would calculate the daily order.

Comment: @uvais, I've edited the question because "order" term was looking confusing. I meant "1st record", "2nd record" as "order". Not like sale orders.

Comment: @bh42 You mean, to store this value somewhere? I don't need that, I need to tcalculate dynamically each time I select rows.

Comment: @kubilay yep, that's what I meant. Ok, so this is not you need :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT id, name, created_at, 
   IF(@prev = date(created_at), @s:=@s+1, @s:=1) AS daily_order, 
   @prev:=date(created_at) as dummy
FROM table1, (SELECT @s:= 0, @prev:='') s
ORDER BY created_at
```

Working demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d3ad43/1

Check this on your data to see the performance impact.

Comment: This is awesome, thanks. This was my alternative if I had to involve subqueries:
(SELECT COUNT( mt2.`id` ) + 1 FROM  `mytable` mt2 WHERE DATE( mt2.`created_at` ) = DATE( mytable.`created_at` ) AND mytable.`created_at` > mt2.`created_at`) AS `daily_order`